# Why the two lists in my function are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a list called list1 and I assigned its value to list2.
However, the  result of list2 is the same with list1? Why is that?

I think the list2 is in front of list1.sort() so that the result of list2 shouldn't same with list1.
Here is my code.

```
list1=[5,4,7,3,8,1,-1]
list2=list1
list3=list1.copy()
list1.sort()
print(list1,list2,list3)
[-1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8] [-1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8] [5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 1, -1]
```

Comment: To do what you clearly expect: Instead of  `list2=list1` do `list2=list1.copy()`  or `list2=list1[:]`. I don't  really understand why you are asking this because your code is already doing the right thing with `list3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list2 = list1`

In line above, `list2` is pointing on the same memory address as `list1`. Means any changes in either `list1` or `list2` will reflect changes on both because lists in python are `mutable`

Check the memory address of variable using `id()`

```
hex(id(list1))
>> '0x1e56d5cb148'

hex(id(list2))
>> '0x1e56d5cb148'
```

Comment: I know what you are taling about, but there is an order between these codes so that list2 has assigned the value of the initial list1, how does lits2 assigned new value of list1.sort()?

Comment: You changed values placed at `memory address of list1` and since list1 and list2 both are pointing to the same location so when you will try to access list2 it will give you updated value. if You will do `list3 = list1` instead of `list3=list1.copy()`, value of list3 would have changed too.

Answer (score 1):

here the value of list2 is changing when you change or modify list1 because list is a mutable data structure in which if you assign list2 to list1 with the equal sign assignment operator then the value of list2 will be changed when you change list1. on the other hand list3 is not changing because it is not assigned to list1 but it is a copy of list1. list is a mutable data structure